# SyntaxError when using tuples in my own sorted key

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, lambda, key

I am trying to create my own key for the sorted function:

```
word_count = {"Papa":3,
              "Maman":2,
              "le":3,
              "la":2,
              "et":7}

# sort the words from highest count to lowest
wc = sorted(word_count.items(), 
            key=lambda (word, count): count, 
            reverse=False)
```

Unfortunately it returns:

```
  File "<ipython-input-20-d325ccb3bd50>", line 8
    key=lambda (word, count): count,
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

As I inspired myself from a Python2 example my guess is that the Syntax has changed.

Answer (score 0):

The key to understanding your error is the realization that the method 'word_count.items()' essentially returns a list of tuples of the form (key, value).  With this in mind you can rewrite your command as follows:

```
wc = sorted(word_count.items(), 
            key=lambda x: x[1], 
            reverse=False)
```

Your lambda x refers to each tuple and you want to sort on the x[1] element.  The above yields the following:

> [('Maman', 2), ('la', 2), ('Papa', 3), ('le', 3), ('et', 7)]